# How do I sum many Counter objects in Python?

Tags: python

If I use Pythons sum function, I get an "unsupported operand type(s)" error, though adding `c1 = Counter(..), c2 = Counter(..)` like this: `c1+c2` works.

Comment: Watch out - this can take quadratic time. It's more efficient to do `sum_counter = Counter()` and `for counter in counters: sum_counter.update(counter)`.

Comment: @user2357112: Or if you're after a one-liner, `reduce(lambda a, b: a.update(b) or b, counters, Counter())`

Comment: @Eric: `operator.iadd` can replace that rather unwieldy `lambda`: `reduce(operator.iadd, counters, Counter())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always read the full error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'
```

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) takes a starting value to sum from, which by default is the integer `0`. You need to specify a starting value of type `Counter`, such as the empty counter:

```
sum([c1, c2, c3], Counter())
```

Or alternatively, spell it:

```
reduce(operator.add, [c1, c2, c3])
```

Comment: Just for information, the full error is not really helping for a beginner. You should post a link to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum